# public repository is not accessible (bitbucket)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm using bitbucket for the first time. I have created a `public repository in bitbucket`. After `pushing code` to the repository I shared link to view the code. But it is not opening always the page is loading after sometime it is showing as `403`. I tried so many things but nothing is working.

[image]

Comment: Try with `https://bitbucket.org/matheenshariff/assignment-19-10-2023`

Comment: Thanks you so much. It is working now. Where to find the repository  link that can be shared?

Comment: It's the same URL as you'd use to clone via HTTPS, just without any `.git` on the end.